# Write MIME file with double-quotes

Tags: c#, mime, escaping, double-quotes

I am manually creating a multi-part MIME-formatted file and submitting it to an SMTP pickup directory.  When the email arrives in my inbox it has lost the opening double-quote of any double-quote terms.  e.g.

```
<html lang="eng">
```

becomes

```
<html lang=ng">
```

I have checked the file before it is submitted to SMTP (PowerMTA) and it does contain all the correct double-quotes etc.

What's happening here, and how do I code around it?  My end-users will be using this solution to create HTML-based outbound email, so it needs to cope with any HTML content.

Comment: Is this an encoding issue? Are you using the correct encoding?

Comment: Quite possibly - this is how I'm writing the HTML section: 

    writer.WriteLine("--" + altBoundary);
    writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html");
    writer.WriteLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable"); writer.WriteLine(); writer.WriteLine(HTMLBody);

Comment: @Greg B - Once again I'd like to say you both answered the question, but I'm unsure whether I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about `"`, it's about `=`
You should convert all your `=` to `=3D`. There are also other limitations that you can find in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable#Quoted-printable_encoding).

Comment: Is there a nice C# one liner that will correctly encode my string?

Comment: Looks like there isn't. However, google search returns various results like this one: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/48017-how-to-decode-quoted-printable-encoded-string/ or http://www.nicecleanexample.com/ViewApp.aspx?TID=quoteprint

Comment: Great - that's done the trick.  I used the nicecleanexample code which worked well.